# Visual studio 2008 and sourcesafe 2005 integration

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-sourcesafe-2005

I understand the labeling and branching of vss, but how do i implement it with visual studio 2008. for example i am labeling all the files in my project as "version 1.0" and then (after that changes checkouts and check ins made) i want to bring version 1.0 back to visual studio.
how do i do that from visual studio? or do i have to do it from VSS?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Within Visual Studio, you can right-click on the solution or project.

- View History command.
- Ensure the "Include Labels" checkbox is checked, and click then OK button.
- Find the version that you're after.
- Click the Get button.
- Confirm that you want to overwrite
- Visual Studio will get all the artifacts under the project/solution for that label.

If your project is NOT under source control, and was not part of the label at that point in time, then you'll have to go back to the VSS GUI to View History by the Label that you like.

Comment: the "view history" unavailable for the project. i can only do it for a file

Comment: @Junk: is your .proj and/or .sln under source control?

Comment: no. my project is a website and for some reason the .proj file is not under source control, while in other project types (class library for example) the proj file is under source control.